# This is my logic to find the middle element in a Linked list using tortoise-hare algorithm

Tags: c++

```
int find_middle_node(struct Node *p)
{
    struct Node *q=NULL;
    
    
    int count=0;
    while(p!=NULL){
        count++;
        p=p->next;
    }
    if(count%2!=0){
        p=q=first;
        while(q!=NULL){
            p=p->next;
            q=q->next;
            q=!q?q:q->next;
        }
        cout<<p->data;
    }
    if(count%2==0){
        p=q=first;
        while(q!=NULL){
            p=p->next;
            q=q->next;
            q=!q->next?q:q->next;
        }
        cout<<p->data;
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```

This is my logic my working.crt me. Where I went wrong??

Comment: What is `first`? You lost the parameter in `p` passed to the function.

Comment: What is `struct Node`? What is `first`? If `first` is a global variable, you're doing it wrong. Anyway, please [edit] and post a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, like telling us the expected and actual behavior and what other debugging efforts you have made. A proper [mre] would also be helpful.

Comment: At my dear previous commenters. There is no MRE needed to see that the line ````q=!q->next?q:q->next; ```` will dereference a ````nullptr````. But I made a MRE for you in my answer. Then you can see it better.

Answer (score 1):

First I created a minimum reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    Node* next{};
    int data{};
};

Node n8{ nullptr,8 }, n7{ &n8,7 }, n6{ &n7,6 }, n5{ &n6,5 }, n4{ &n5, 4}, n3{ &n4,3 }, n2{ &n3,2 }, n1{ &n2,1 };
Node* first = &n1;

int find_middle_node(struct Node* p)
{
    struct Node* q = NULL;

    int count = 0;
    while (p != NULL) {
        count++;
        p = p->next;
    }
    if (count % 2 != 0) {
        p = q = first;
        while (q != NULL) {
            p = p->next;
            q = q->next;
            q = !q ? q : q->next;
        }
        std::cout << p->data;
    }
    if (count % 2 == 0) {
        p = q = first;
        while (q != NULL) {
            p = p->next;
            q = q->next;
            q=!q->next?q:q->next;
        }
        std::cout << (p->data);
    }
    return 0;
}
// Test
int main() {

    // Now, check for middle with even number of elements
    Node* temp = first;
    find_middle_node(temp);

    // Remove on element
    first = first->next;
    temp = first;
    find_middle_node(temp);
}
```

Then I made a review of your code and saw the line:

```
q=!q->next?q:q->next;
```

If q at this point in time is already `nullptr` then you cannot dereference it with `q->next ?` . The program will crash.

You may replace the line by

```
 if (q and q->next) q = q->next;
```

Then, you are on the safe side.

If your code has something to do with *Tortoise and Hare*? I am not sure. The only thing is, that you try to advance the next pointers 2 times for even numbers and 3 times for odd numbers. The last one is wrong in my opinion.

So, your algorithm may still be broken. Always the element past the middle will be returned. Then, better to remember one p from the loop run before.

Maybe this could be a solution:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    Node* next{};
    int data{};
};

Node n8{ nullptr,8 }, n7{ &n8,7 }, n6{ &n7,6 }, n5{ &n6,5 }, n4{ &n5, 4}, n3{ &n4,3 }, n2{ &n3,2 }, n1{ &n2,1 };
Node* first = &n1;

int find_middle_node(struct Node* p)
{
    struct Node* q = NULL;
    
    p = q = first;
    Node* oldP = p;

    while (q != NULL) {
        oldP = p;
        p = p->next;
        q = q->next;
        q = !q ? q : q->next;
    }
    std::cout << oldP->data << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
// Test
int main() {

    // Now, check for middle with even number of elements
    Node* temp = first;
    find_middle_node(temp);

    // Remove on element
    first = first->next;
    temp = first;
    find_middle_node(temp);
}
```

More `nullptr` checking should be added.

But i am not sure about the whole thing. . .